# Create a clone of Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IMetaFactory {
    String imageId = new String();
    // some default methods
    void setImageId(String id);
    default String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
}
```

I need to add a clone method in this interface such that when I call:

```
IMetaFactory mf = metafactory.clone();
```

It returns a new copy of `IMetaFactory`, so that I can set a new `imageID` in it.

```
mf.setImageId("abc");
```

How do I achieve it? Clone method inside the interface just overflows the stack (obviously).

Comment: Why you choose Interface, Why not abstract class with abstract method clone().

Comment: Why do you need clone at all, as opposed to just having `imageId` as a member variable, and then just create a new instance when you want it?

Comment: Side-note: are you aware that fields defined in interface are `final`?

Comment: *Clone method inside the interface just overflows the stack (obviously)*: What is obvious about that? What have you actually tried?

Comment: @user7790438 Can you please elaborate (perhaps in an answer?)

Comment: Better try to explaining *what* you're trying to achieve instead of *how* you're trying to do it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could use abstract class with abstract clone() method that every class inherit from that abstract class implement the clone method and return this:

```
public abstract class MetaFactory {
    String imageId = new String();
    // some default methods
    void setImageId(String id);
    default String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public abstract MetaFactory clone();
}
```

and in any of the inherited classes implement the abstract class as follow:

```
public class A extends MetaFactory  {
    //the lone method implementation
    public MetaFactory clone(){
        return this;
    }
}
```